# The tab widths of new-nav are too short

Tags: feature-request, new-nav, user-interface

[image]

As titled. The tabs are *too* short. 100px is not even enough to show "need answers" completely. The maximum width should be longer (e.g. 300px).

(btw the <kbd>+ new tab</kbd> button can be changed to just <kbd>+</kbd> to save some space)

Comment: Or even make the new tab button a “tab” too.